# Java get enum array values?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an enum whose member constructors contains a list of another enum. Is it possible to auto complete / gain visibility of items in the enum's array list? Please see the code below.

I would like to gain visibility of the columns in a given table. Is it possible to do so?

DatabaseDefinitions.Tables.marketOrders.columns.id // How can it be done?

```
public class DatabaseDefinitions {
    public static enum Tables {
        marketOrders(new Columns[]{Columns.id,
            Columns.symbol,
            Columns.orderType,
            Columns.quantity,
            Columns.priceLimit,
            Columns.priceStop,
            Columns.goodAfterDate,
            Columns.goodUntilDate,
            Columns.priceAverageFill}),
        ;

        public Columns[] columns;

        Tables(Columns[] columns){
            this.columns = columns;
        }
    }

    public static enum Columns {
        id,
        symbol,
        orderType,
        quantity,
        priceLimit,
        priceStop,
        goodAfterDate,
        goodUntilDate,
        priceAverageFill,
        exchange,
        currency,
        securityType,
        price,
        sizeBid,
        sizeAsk,
        sizeLast,
        sizeVolume,
        dateTime,
    }

    public static enum Queries {

    }
}
```

Comment: One more thing: please follow Java naming code conventions and use CAPITALISED_VALUE_NAMES for Enums, like for constants (i.e. final static variables). Please see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Answer (score 0):

I would add a public getter in `Tables` class/enum.

```
public Columns[] getColumns() {
    return this.columns;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Oops, 'columns' is a 'public' array already. Then what is a question? You can easily access array of columns in this case and each its item, e.g.

```
if ( DatabaseDefinitions.Tables.marketOrders.columns[0].equals( Columns.id ) ) {
  // ...
}
```

Meanwhile, I would make 'columns' array 'private' and give an access through a getter. But it may depend on your particular task.

Comment: For an array a `public getter` is almost as bad.

Comment: At a minimum, make the array columns final.  Not the solution to everything but a start.

Comment: Much better: return an unmodifiable List wrapper.

Comment: @MiserableVariable As an option, it can return a copy of array, instead of original one. But generally, I don't know how Kevin does use it at whole, what particular functionality is required. Probably, it's better to replace array with Set or List, for example.

Comment: Well I knew that I could get the columns that way, but its not bound to a specific table if I do it like that. I would might as well call Columns.id rather than Tables.maketOrders.id...